# Nothing is displayed even after using try catch block

Tags: java, android, json

this block neither gives an error in the log nor does  it put any value in the string body

```
    try {
        int roll = 00111502713;
        //url defined is completely fine//
        URL url = new URL("someurl");
        URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
        InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
        encoding = con.getContentEncoding();
        encoding = encoding == null ? "UTF-8" : encoding;
        try {
            body = IOUtils.toString(in, encoding);
            Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this, "Body found", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Log_tag", "Hahaha");

        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        //     System.out.println("This shouldn't have happened");
        Log.e("Log_Tag", "Really?");
    }
```

Comment: Where are you trying to display `body`?

Comment: check url in browser, is it returning you any data?

Comment: yup it is
a full json string

Comment: Where are you looking to get the value of `body`?  Have you tried `Log.e("Log_tag", body)`?  Right now you are just assigning it to a variable, not displaying it.

Comment: @Dithanial I was trying to display it.. but it wasn't happening

Comment: Can you suggest me any way to display it?

Comment: @Dithanial it is showing

  "The application may be doing too much work on its main thread."

Comment: Why don't you use the debugger?  Much better than logging and guessing.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call:

```
Toast.makeText(FirstActivity.this,"Body found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: I'll do that for sure..but there is no value in String body either